# Existe alguma maneira de fazer toggle com atributos no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

No `JQuery`, temos uma função chamada `toggle` que nos permite alternar entre o elemento ficar visível ou não. E a função `toggleClass`, que permite alternar entre a inclusão de uma classe ou não.

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('button').click(function () { 
    
     $('div').toggle();
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:none">Estou aqui</div>

<button>Click</button>
```

Porém eu tenho a necessidade de "colocar e tirar" um atributo da mesma maneira que essa função faz. Quero fazer isso com o atributo `required` num `input`.

Tem como fazer isso no jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode criar algo com [`jQuery.fn`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/), assim:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  toggleAttribute: function(attr, value) {
    if (typeof value !== "string") {
        value = "true";
    }

    //Pega os elementos que tem o atributo
    var withAttr = this.filter("[" + attr + "]");

    //Pega os elementos sem o atributo
    var noAttr = this.filter(":not([" + attr + "])");

    //Se for classes então não usamos attr, porque classes funcionam diferente
    if (attr === "class") {
        noAttr.addClass(value);
        withAttr.removeClass(value);
    } else {
        noAttr.attr(attr, value);
        withAttr.removeAttr(attr);
    }

    return this;
  }
});
```

O uso fica assim para automaticamente adicionar `required` ou remover:

```
$('button').click(function () { 
    $('input').toggleAttribute("required");
});
```

O uso fica assim para automaticamente adicionar o atributo `foo` com o valor `baz` ou remover:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').toggleAttribute("foo", "baz");
});
```

Comment: Pènsei nisso mesmo, chefe, mas de maneira que iria funcionar para qualquer atributo. De qualquer forma +1 ;)

Comment: @WallacedeSouza já corrigi... pois é né ... pra ***eu*** ganhar upvotes os caras veem de carroça (isso quando ganho, porque virou raridade), pra ***eu*** ganhar downvote os caras veem de foguete...

Comment: Tiraram e colocaram o voto (tira e põe várias vezes). Acho que alguém está brincando por conta da pergunta ser justamente sobre toggle. rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: @WallacedeSouza era uma extensão jQuery chamada `toggleHater.js`, funciona assim `$("@guilhermenascimento").toggleHater();`

Answer (score 2):

Igual ao toggle não tem, mas tem o [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) que adiciona um atributo e o [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) que remove.